# hover a anchor tag change another anchor tag style

Tags: html, css

I make two-button with the anchor tag. one name is read more and one name is contact me. but I want to change the hover state .means when I hover my read more button I want to change my contact me button style and when I hover contact me button I want to change my read more button style.is this possible? plz someone help.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: coral;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .hero-btn {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px 30px;
            background-color: #fff;
            font-size: 15px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: 600;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }

        .hero-btn2 {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 15px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 600;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            padding: 10px 30px;
            color: #fff;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" class="hero-btn">Read more</a>
    <a href="#" class="hero-btn2">Contact me</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: with pure css you can only affect the subsequent siblings.. in you case you can change the style of the hero-btn2 when hovering over hero-btn with `.hero-btn:hover + a`, but not the other way around as css selectors don't grab parents or before coming siblings.. you need js for that

Comment: yea thanks, bro. but I already try this. I want to change both .but not work.

Comment: That's what I'm saying.. you need JS for that.. very simple though

Comment: It's not possible to have a general-purpose solution (i.e. for any number of anchor elements and any form of re-styling) without JS as @zergski has pointed out, but with just 2 anchor elements you can do it, and I've put that in an answer. For more than 2, and depending on what re-styling you want, you may be able to use the same technique or add things with pseudo elements, but it can get messy and for the completely general situation with >2 anchor elements you need JS.

Comment: thanks, sir I really want to that we can do it with CSS or not and you did it.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the two anchor elements in the same container you can pick up on hover on the container as well as on an individual anchor element and so change the other one (via the container hover) and the hovered anchor element (via hovering on itself).

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: coral;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .hero-btn {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px 30px;
            background-color: #fff;
            font-size: 15px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: 600;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }

        .hero-btn2 {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 15px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 600;
            background-color: transparent;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            padding: 10px 30px;
            color: #fff;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        
        div.container:hover a.hero-btn { background-color: magenta; }
        
        div.container:hover a.hero-btn2 { background-color: cyan; }
        
        div.container:hover a.hero-btn:hover { background-color: lime; }
        
        div.container:hover a.hero-btn2:hover { background-color: red; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="hero-btn">Read more</a>
    <a href="#" class="hero-btn2">Contact me</a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```